# Tradução das medalhas explainer, refiner e illuminator

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução

As medalhas [explainer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/115/explainer), [refiner](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/116/refiner) e [illuminator](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/117/illuminator) estão com os nomes e descrições em inglês, elas foram adicionadas recentemente.

Relacionado: [MSE - new three tiered badge idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239898/new-three-tiered-badge-idea-explainer-refiner-illuminator)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Sugestões

- **Intérprete**
- **Aprimorador**
- **Luminar** (porém é ambíguo) ou **Exegeta** (pedante demais?)

Essas medalhas estão mais difíceis de traduzir do que as outras. Principalmente a de ouro, que – na minha interpretação – já tem um duplo sentido embutido (*iluminar* no sentido de *esclarecer* e de *fazer iluminuras*).

Comment: Sinceramente, nunca tinha ouvido falar essa 'exegeta'. Vivendo e aprendendo.

Comment: Pois é, a palavra é meio obscura, e por isso mesmo não é um nome muito bom. É que não estou tendo boas ideias pra essa de ouro.

Comment: Resolvido, usando **Luminar**. O texto da medalha ficou: "Editou e respondeu NN pergunta (em um intervalo de 12h, resposta com pontuação > 0)"

Comment: Falta o "s" em pergunta para o caso de NN > 1